# Difficulty in finding error in perl script

Tags: perl

Its a kind of bioinformatics concept but programmatic problem. I've tried a lot and at last I came here. I've reads like following.

```
ATGGAAG
TGGAAGT
GGAAGTC
GAAGTCG
AAGTCGC
AGTCGCG
GTCGCGG
TCGCGGA
CGCGGAA
GCGGAAT
CGGAATC
```

Now what I want to do is, in a simplistic way,

take the last 6 residues of first read -> check if any other read is starting with those 6 residues, if yes add the last residue of that read to the first read -> again same with the 2nd read and so on.

Here is the code what I've tried so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $in = $ARGV[0];
open(IN, $in);
my @short_reads = <IN>;
my $first_read = $short_reads[0];
chomp $first_read;
my @all_end_res;


for(my $i=0; $i<=$#short_reads; $i++){
        chomp $short_reads[$i];
        my $end_of_kmers = substr($short_reads[$i], -6);
        if($short_reads[$i+1] =~ /^$end_of_kmers/){
                my $end_res = substr($short_reads[$i], -1);
                push(@all_end_res, $end_res);
        }

}

my $end_res2 = join('', @all_end_res);
print $first_read.$end_res2,"\n\n";
```

At the end I should get an output like `ATGGAAGTCGCGGAATC` but I'm getting `ATGGAAGGTCGCGGAAT`. The error must be in `if`, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `use warnings;` should be complaining about something. Have you taken a closer look at the warning running this program yields?

Comment: (If you're not seeing anything: when I run it, at least, I get: `Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at bio.pl line 16, <IN> line 11.`)

Comment: Yep, I am also getting the same. Is this the wrong way to use a variable in regex?

Comment: It's because during the last iteration of the script `$short_reads[$i+1]` doesn't exist (and is `undef`)

Comment: `$short_reads[$i+1]` is uninitialized if `$i` is already `$#short_reads` (in your final loop iteration): you're reading past the end of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three huge problems in IT.

1. Naming of things.
2. Off by one error.

And you just hit the second one. The problem is in a way you think about this task. You think in way *I have this one string and if **next** one overlap I will add this one character to result.* But correct way to think in this case *I have this one string and if it overlaps with **previous** string or what I read so far, I will add one character or characters which are next.*

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use constant LENGTH => 6;

my $read = <>;
chomp $read;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    last unless length > LENGTH;
    if ( substr( $read, -LENGTH() ) eq substr( $_, 0, LENGTH ) ) {
        $read .= substr( $_, LENGTH );
    }
    else {last}
}

print $read, "\n";
```

I didn't get this `ARGV[0]` thing. It is useless and inflexible.

```
$ chmod +x code.pl
$ cat data
ATGGAAG
TGGAAGT
GGAAGTC
GAAGTCG
AAGTCGC
AGTCGCG
GTCGCGG
TCGCGGA
CGCGGAA
GCGGAAT
CGGAATC
$ ./code.pl data 
ATGGAAGTCGCGGAATC
```

But you have not defined what should happen if data doesn't overlap. Should there be some recovery or error? You can be also more strict

```
last unless length == LENGTH + 1;
```

**Edit**:

If you like working with an array you should try avoid using `for(;;)`. It is prone to errors. (BTW `for (my $i = 0; $i < @a; $i++)` is more idiomatic.)

```
my @short_reads = <>;
chomp @short_reads;

my @all_end_res;
for my $i (1 .. $#short_reads) {
    my $prev_read = $short_reads[$i-1];
    my $curr_read = $short_reads[$i+1];
    my $end_of_kmers = substr($prev_read, -6);
    if ( $curr_read =~ /^\Q$end_of_kmers(.)/ ) {
        push @all_end_res, $1;
    }
}

print $short_reads[0], join('', @all_end_res), "\n";
```

The performance and memory difference is negligible up to thousands of lines. Now you can ask why to accumulate characters into an array instead of accumulate it to string.

```
my @short_reads = <>;
chomp @short_reads;

my $read = $short_reads[0];
for my $i (1 .. $#short_reads) {
    my $prev_read = $short_reads[$i-1];
    my $curr_read = $short_reads[$i+1];
    my $end_of_kmers = substr($prev_read, -6);
    if ( $curr_read =~ /^\Q$end_of_kmers(.)/ ) {
        $read .= $1;
    }
}

print "$read\n";
```

Now the question is why to use `$prev_read` when you have `$end_of_kmers` inside of `$read`.

```
my @short_reads = <>;
chomp @short_reads;

my $read = $short_reads[0];
for my $i (1 .. $#short_reads) {
    my $curr_read = $short_reads[$i+1];
    my $end_of_kmers = substr($read, -6);
    if ( $curr_read =~ /^\Q$end_of_kmers(.)/ ) {
        $read .= $1;
    }
}

print "$read\n";
```

Now you can ask why I need indexes at all. You just should remove the first line to work with the rest of array.

```
my @short_reads = <>;
chomp @short_reads;

my $read = shift @short_reads;
for my $curr_read (@short_reads) {
    my $end_of_kmers = substr($read, -6);
    if ( $curr_read =~ /^\Q$end_of_kmers(.)/ ) {
        $read .= $1;
    }
}

print "$read\n";
```

And with few more steps and tweaks you will end up with the code what I posted initially. I don't need an array at all because I look only to the current line and accumulator. The difference is in a way how you think about the problem. If you think in terms of arrays and indexes and looping or in terms of data flow, data processing and state/accumulator. With more experience, you don't have to do all those steps and make the final solution just due different approach to problem solving.

**Edit2**:

It is almost ten times faster using `substr` and `eq` then using regular expressions.

```
$ time ./code.pl data.out > data.test  

real    0m0.480s
user    0m0.468s
sys     0m0.008s
$ time ./code2.pl data.out > data2.test

real    0m4.520s
user    0m4.516s
sys     0m0.000s
$ cmp data.test data2.test && echo OK
OK
$ wc -c data.out data.test
6717368 data.out
839678 data.test
```

Comment: Thank you. No need of doing anything if data doesn't overlap.

Comment: Out of interest, what's the 3rd problem in IT (you only give 2)?

Comment: @fugu: It is part of the joke. You tell kind of error and make one just on the spot. There is a version you start _There are two huge problems_ and then tell three of them. Insert cache invalidation as second one and put _off by one_ as third one. It is sad to have to explain jokes.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil - gotcha! I'm not from an IT background so don't feel bad about explaining the joke (and I won't feel stupid for not understanding it). I wanted to say that you'd committed both errors in your statement, but thought that it would come across a bit snide

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil If I also want to print the data that is not overlapped, can I use the else statement to send the data into an array?

Comment: @nEU: Yes, of course, but you have to remove the `last` part if you would like all of them. The keyword `last` will end the cycle. You can change `last` to `next` in length checking statement to just ignore wrong lines and so on.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil Excellent. This part I will try on my own. Your script is a pro level one, You must have understood from my code that I am a novice. I always worry about perl, many a times it is a bit difficult to understand someones code, at least for me.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will keep these things in mind always when I sit to code.

Answer (score 0):

with minor modification:

```
use warnings;
use strict;


open my $in, '<', $ARGV[0] or die $!;
chomp(my @short_reads = <$in>);

my $first_read = $short_reads[0];

my @all_end_res;

for(my $i=0; $i<=$#short_reads; $i++){
        chomp $short_reads[$i];
        my $end_of_kmers = substr($short_reads[$i], -6);
        my ($next_read) = $short_reads[$i+1];
        if( (defined $next_read) and ($next_read =~ /^\Q$end_of_kmers/)){
                 my $end_res = substr($next_read, -1);
                 push(@all_end_res, $end_res);
         }

}

my $end_res2 = join('', @all_end_res);
print $first_read.$end_res2,"\n";
```

---

```
ATGGAAGTCGCGGAATC
```

Comment: it is only printing upto `ATGGAAGTCGCGGAAT` I don't find C at the end.

Comment: Try copying and pasting the whole program. Does it still not produce the desired output?

Comment: `Name "main::DATA" used only once: possible typo at stack2.pl line 4.
readline() on unopened filehandle DATA at stack2.pl line 4.
Use of uninitialized value $first_read in concatenation (.) or string at stack2.pl line 22.` This is what I'm getting.

Comment: @nEU - I don't know why it would throw that error - reading in from `<DATA>` always works for me. I've changed it back to how you originally had it, and it still produces the desired output

Comment: still I don't get the desired output, 'C' is missing at the end of result

Comment: @nEU - Are we both using the same input? Literally copy and paste my script, and the input you've provided in the question. If it produces a different result then I'm stumped I'm afraid